# Create view similar to Facebook App in iOS

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios5

I need to create a iOS app where the main screen is very similar to the Facebook iOS App. I am using a UITableView to show the different posts in the feed. My question is:

What is the best option to implement this? One option is to insert Textviews/Imageviews/labels to the table view cell and another option is to have one UIWebView in each table view cell.
I have to show a lot of pictures and texts, so maybe html will be easier.

Any experience?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to show a lot of pictures and text, adding one complexity level (like HTML) is not gonna help.

I'd suggest to start researching on how you can speed that huge table up, and how to retrieve the content you want to display on each cell. For instance, you could use a parallel thread that would retrieve the content in the background as you scroll down and would store it in a cache so it doesn't have to be done several times. [RestKit](http://restkit.org/) or (depending on your specific needs) [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) are surely of some help in your case.

Also, have a look to this article (a bit old, but still interesting!) on how improve your scrolling speed: [Fast scrolling](http://web.archive.org/web/20100322222950/http://blog.atebits.com/2008/12/fast-scrolling-in-tweetie-with-uitableview/) (and link to github [example project](https://github.com/adamalex/fast-scrolling))

Comment: The images have different sizes. How do you think that I can resize them in iOS? In HTML I just need to adjust the css (i.e. background-size: cover)

Comment: Just set the contentMode of your UIImageView to UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill and you should get the same effect.